Potential PhD supervisor recommended me to the Director of another university research group, is this a good or bad sign?
So one of the potential PhD advisors at a university let's say X whom I emailed didn't reply but recommended me to another professor who is the Director of another university's say Y's research group. The universities X and Y have research affiliations and these professors know each other personally. I know this because the email with an invitation for interview which I received from Y explicitly stated this. Should I take this as a good sign and go ahead with the formal departmental application process for the first university X (normal admission process here in Canada for engineering) or this indicates that I am not a good fit for X hence the recommendation for Y? I am asking because although the research group of Y is good and relevant to my interests and credentials (hence the recommendation!) but I actually prefer being in the research group of university X as it has a better ranking and research culture overall. Also is this act of recommendation a normal practice specifically in Canada?

Somewhat similar, but the PhD program I got into was not the one I applied to. What was ultimately my program would go and comb through application files in other departments for suitable candidates. So one day I got a call from the department chair asking if I would consider their offer...

I cannot say for sure for the last part of your question since I have neither been to any Canadian university nor know the culture and research practices there. However, generally, yes it is a good sign when a professor recommends you to another research group. In academic, professors and research groups do a lot of collaborative work, so such recommendation is natural. Normally, most of the professors refrain to do so. Well, it could also be possible that prof at X university does not have funding or open position in his group. And as the cliche' goes (again not sure if valid in Canada), at PhD level, it is your research that counts than the ranking of your university.
